# How to do reduce rows with Wolfram Alpha over certain set

Tags: matrices, wolfram-alpha

If I want to row reduce a matrix:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 & 4 \\
        2 & -2 & 1 & 3 \\
        5 & -5 & 1 & 15 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

over $$\mathbb{Z}_3$$ is there a way I can do this in Wolfram Alpha? Thanks!

Comment: @Amzoti very true, that's what I've been doing. Just wondering if there was an easier way

Comment: cool, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Use the syntax I have written [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RowReduce%5B%7B%7B1%2C+-1%2C+0%2C+4%7D%2C+%7B2%2C+-2%2C+1%2C+3%7D%2C+%7B5%2C+-5%2C+1%2C+15%7D%7D%5D), then reduce mod 3 manually.

I just typed:

```
RowReduce[{{1, -1, 0, 4}, {2, -2, 1, 3}, {5, -5, 1, 15}}]
```

As Amzoti points out well, and I just found out through test, WA just kinda burps on adding the `Modulus->3` parameter.

Go to [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/), sign in to the "Wolfram Programming Cloud", and have your way with the Mathematica syntax. If you do it there, the statement

```
MatrixForm[
 RowReduce[{{1, -1, 0, 4}, {2, -2, 1, 3}, {5, -5, 1, 15}}, 
  Modulus -> 3]]
```

will give you that which you desire with no cost. :)

Comment: By "no cost", I mean basic Wolfram Programming Cloud accounts are free, and so get one. It is the solution, and a beautiful thing. What you can do with a free account might possibly split your brain. I am wondering if anyone outside of the Wolfram fan base knows this.